# Proper way of connecting to a dynamic data source

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, vb.net

***Which technology should I use for data access layer?***

What's the best way of connecting to a **dynamic data source** and binding the result to a grid?

I'm writing a little **web app** that user can define connection string and table name (MS Sql Server) and the program will display values in that table inside a grid.

We must use **datasets** (because of dynamic data source) and generate the query as a **text command** ("Select * From " + TableName).

We don't have a model (data source is defined by user at run time) so we can not use **EF**.

*What do you think? Should I use datasets? Is there any better solution out there?*

I'm not looking for a sample code here. I'm looking for the **best way of connecting to data source**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Should I use datasets?"

I don't see why not. They are easy to code against, and can bind to gridviews and repeaters easily. They can be populated using text queries as well. Though I would caution you against SQL injection attacks. So if you do go the way of the text SQL commands make sure to scrutinize the user input.

Comment: Any links that suggests I'm on the right direction by using datasets?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for, but here's a quick little article that uses ADO.NET and datasets to populate a grid.

Comment: I know how to bind datasets to a grid or use DataAdapter, etc.. I'm looking for an article or an open source project that suggests using datasets is best way of connecting to a dynamic data source and there is no better way.

Comment: There is no such thing. There are multiple ways to solve the same problem for a reason. We all have difference circumstances and requirements. What might work best for you does not necessarily work the best for me. Validation for your choice should come from you.